# edit: script for editing metadata in Adobe Bridge - how should I put "Key Words" (separate words) into code?

Tags: javascript, function, extendscript, photoshop-script, adobe-bridge

I have a simple script for editing metadata in Adobe Bridge with find and replace functionality. It is for Description section only.

I need to make it work for Keywords section only instead. I tried to change `description` into `keywords` (with and without `Description` > `Keywords`), but the end result is the script which doesn't work. What (else) needs to be changed or added in order to achieve what I need?

**edit**:

I tried to change `description` into `title` to make the script work for the Title section and it worked.

### So the question is what exactly should replace `description` to make this work for the Keywords section?

I saw in one script that for Bridge it should be `Key Words` (separate), so if that's the case, how should I write that in the code? (yes, I'm a noob in javascript)

**Find Replace In Description.jsx** - [link to github](https://github.com/Paul-Riggott/PS-Scripts/blob/master/Find%20Replace%20In%20Description.jsx)

```
#target bridge
if( BridgeTalk.appName == "bridge" ) {
ReplaceDescription = new MenuElement("command", "Find and Replace", "at the end of tools");
}
ReplaceDescription.onSelect = function () {
var win = new Window( 'dialog', 'Find && Replace' );
g = win.graphics;
var myBrush = g.newBrush(g.BrushType.SOLID_COLOR, [0.99, 0.99, 0.99, 1]);
g.backgroundColor = myBrush;
win.orientation='column';
win.p1= win.add("panel", undefined, undefined, {borderStyle:"black"});
win.p1.preferredSize=[380,100];
win.g1 = win.p1.add('group');
win.g1.orientation = "row";
win.title = win.g1.add('statictext',undefined,'Caption Editor');
win.title.alignment="fill";
var g = win.title.graphics;
g.font = ScriptUI.newFont("Georgia","BOLDITALIC",22);
win.p6= win.p1.add("panel", undefined, undefined, {borderStyle:"black"}); //Replace
win.p6.preferredSize=[380,100];
win.g600 =win.p6.add('group');
win.g600.orientation = "row";
win.g600.alignment='fill';
win.g600.st1 = win.g600.add('statictext',undefined,'Replace');
win.g600.st1.preferredSize=[75,20];
win.g600.et1 = win.g600.add('edittext');
win.g600.et1.preferredSize=[200,20];
win.g610 =win.p6.add('group');
win.g610.orientation = "row";
win.g610.alignment='fill';
win.g610.st1 = win.g610.add('statictext',undefined,'With');
win.g610.st1.helpTip="Leave this field blank if you want to remove the characters";
win.g610.st1.preferredSize=[75,20];
win.g610.et1 = win.g610.add('edittext');
win.g610.et1.preferredSize=[200,20];
win.g620 =win.p6.add('group');
win.g620.orientation = "row";
win.g620.alignment='fill';
win.g620.cb1 = win.g620.add('checkbox',undefined,'Global');
win.g620.cb1.helpTip="Replace all occurrences of";
win.g620.cb2 = win.g620.add('checkbox',undefined,'Case Insensitive');
win.g620.cb2.value=true;
win.g620.cb3 = win.g620.add('checkbox',undefined,'Remove any ()[]');
win.g620.cb3.value=false;
win.g1000 =win.p1.add('group');
win.g1000.orientation = "row";
win.g1000.alignment='center';
win.g1000.bu1 = win.g1000.add('button',undefined,'Process');
win.g1000.bu1.preferredSize=[170,30];
win.g1000.bu2 = win.g1000.add('button',undefined,'Cancel');
win.g1000.bu2.preferredSize=[170,30];
win.g1000.bu1.onClick=function(){
if(win.g600.et1.text == ''){
alert("No replace value has been entered!");
return;
}
win.close(0);
var sels = app.document.selections;
for(var a in sels){
var thumb = sels[a];
md = thumb.synchronousMetadata;
if(win.g620.cb1.value && !win.g620.cb2.value) var patt = new RegExp (win.g600.et1.text.toString(),"g");
if(!win.g620.cb1.value && win.g620.cb2.value) var patt = new RegExp (win.g600.et1.text.toString(),"i");
if(win.g620.cb1.value && win.g620.cb2.value) var patt = new RegExp (win.g600.et1.text.toString(),"gi");
if(!win.g620.cb1.value && !win.g620.cb2.value) var patt = new RegExp (win.g600.et1.text.toString());
md.namespace = "http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/";
var Caption = md.description ? md.description[0] : "";
if(Caption == "") continue;
var result=patt.test(Caption.toString());
if(result == true){
var newCaption = Caption.replace(patt,win.g610.et1.text.toString());
if(win.g620.cb3.value) newCaption = newCaption.replace(/["'\(\)]/g, "");
md.description='';
md.description = newCaption;
}
}
}
win.show();
app.document.chooseMenuItem("PurgeCacheForSelected");
};
```

Comment: I'd played around with metadata before and it should be a simple question of replacing one string with another. Have you tried distilling your script into minimum code - get & alert description & then changing it?

Comment: I simply tested the script in Adobe Bridge. Also the thing is that I don't know pretty much nothing about javascript, so when I look at this code idk what else can be done beside changing `description` to `keywords` in it...

Comment: It works when I change it to 'title' for the Title section. I saw somewhere that maybe I should put `key words` instead of `keywords` - how do I put this in the code? I was trying but it didn't work.

Comment: Looks like you solved your own problem. Nice one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a different script which provides the functionality I need, and even better since it gives the option to add and remove keywords:

```
#target bridge  

   if( BridgeTalk.appName == "bridge" ) {  
keyReplace = MenuElement.create("command", "Add-Replace-Remove Keyword", "at the end of tools");
}
keyReplace.onSelect = function () { 
      mainReplaceKeyword();
      }

function mainReplaceKeyword(){
if(app.version.substr(0,app.version.indexOf('.'))==1){
alert("Sorry You Need CS3 or CS4 to run this script!"); 
return;
    }
var dlg =
"dialog{text:'Script Interface',bounds:[100,100,500,310],"+
"panel0:Panel{bounds:[10,10,390,200] , text:'' ,properties:{borderStyle:'etched',su1PanelCoordinates:true},"+
"title:StaticText{bounds:[60,10,350,40] , text:'Add/Replace/Remove Keyword' ,properties:{scrolling:undefined,multiline:undefined}},"+
"panel1:Panel{bounds:[10,40,370,150] , text:'' ,properties:{borderStyle:'etched',su1PanelCoordinates:true},"+
"addKey:Checkbox{bounds:[20,10,160,31] , text:'Add Keyword' },"+
"statictext1:StaticText{bounds:[20,40,119,60] , text:'Replace' ,properties:{scrolling:undefined,multiline:undefined}},"+
"From:EditText{bounds:[120,40,350,60] , text:'' ,properties:{multiline:false,noecho:false,readonly:false}},"+
"statictext2:StaticText{bounds:[20,80,90,97] , text:'With' ,properties:{scrolling:undefined,multiline:undefined}},"+
"To:EditText{bounds:[120,80,350,100] , text:'' ,properties:{multiline:false,noecho:false,readonly:false}}},"+
"button0:Button{bounds:[10,160,180,181] , text:'Ok' },"+
"button1:Button{bounds:[200,160,370,181] , text:'Cancel' }}};";
var win = new Window(dlg,"Replace Keyword");
win.center();

win.panel0.title.graphics.font = ScriptUI.newFont("Times","BOLDITALIC",20);
g = win.graphics;
b=win.panel0.title.graphics;
var myBrush = g.newBrush(g.BrushType.SOLID_COLOR, [0.99, 0.99, 0.20, 1]);
g.backgroundColor = myBrush;
var myPen =b.newPen (g.PenType.SOLID_COLOR, [0.00, 0.00, 0.99, 1],lineWidth=1);
var myPen2 =b.newPen (g.PenType.SOLID_COLOR, [0.99, 0.00, 0.00, 1],lineWidth=1);
g.foregroundColor = myPen;
b.foregroundColor = myPen2;
win.panel0.panel1.From.active=true;
win.panel0.panel1.addKey.onClick = function() { 
if(win.panel0.panel1.addKey.value) {
    win.panel0.panel1.statictext1.text = "New Keyword";
    win.panel0.panel1.From.active=true;
    win.panel0.panel1.statictext2.visible=false;
    win.panel0.panel1.To.visible=false;
    }
if(!win.panel0.panel1.addKey.value) {
    win.panel0.panel1.statictext1.text = "Replace";
    win.panel0.panel1.statictext2.visible=true;
    win.panel0.panel1.To.visible=true;
    win.panel0.panel1.From.active=true;
    }
}
win.center();
var done = false; 
    while (!done) { 
      var x = win.show(); 
      if (x == 0 || x == 2) {
        win.canceled = true;
        done = true; 
      } else if (x == 1) { 
        done = true; 
       var result = valiDate();
        if(result != true) {
            alert(result);
            return;
        }else{    
            var Replace = win.panel0.panel1.From.text;
            var With = win.panel0.panel1.To.text;
            var addKey = win.panel0.panel1.addKey.value;
            processKeyword(Replace,With,addKey);
        }
      } 
   } 

function valiDate(){
    if(win.panel0.panel1.From.text =='') return "No Keyword Entered!";
return true;
}
function processKeyword(Replace,Witha,ddKey){
try{
loadXMPScript();
}catch(e){
alert("Can not load XMPScript\r" + e.message);  
    }

var items = app.document.selections;
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++){ 
      var file=new Thumbnail(items[i]);
try{
var xmpFile = new XMPFile(file.path, XMPConst.UNKNOWN,XMPConst.OPEN_FOR_UPDATE);
}catch(e){
        alert("Problem opening xmp for update:-\r" + file.path +"\r" +e.message);
        return;
    }
try{
var xmp = xmpFile.getXMP();
}catch(e){
        alert("Problem opening xmp data:-\r"  + e.message);
        return;
    }
try{
var tmpCount =  xmp.countArrayItems(XMPConst.NS_DC, "subject");
}catch(e){
    alert("Cannot get count \r" + e.message);
    }
            if(addKey){
                xmp.appendArrayItem(XMPConst.NS_DC, "subject", Replace, 0,XMPConst.ARRAY_IS_ORDERED);
                }
if(tmpCount >0 && !addKey){
        for (var a =0;a<tmpCount;a++){
            var     Keyword = xmp.getArrayItem(XMPConst.NS_DC,'subject', a+1);
            if(Keyword == Replace && With == '') {
                xmp.deleteArrayItem(XMPConst.NS_DC,'subject', a+1);
                }
            if(Keyword == Replace && With != ''){
                xmp.setArrayItem(XMPConst.NS_DC,'subject', a+1,With);
                }
        }
}

if (xmpFile.canPutXMP(xmp)) {
xmpFile.putXMP(xmp);
}else{
alert(e.message);   
    }
xmpFile.closeFile(XMPConst.CLOSE_UPDATE_SAFELY);
}
unloadXMPScript();
}
}

function loadXMPScript()
{
    var results = new XMPLibMsg("XMPScript Library already loaded", 0, false);

    if (!ExternalObject.AdobeXMPScript)
    {
        try
        {
            ExternalObject.AdobeXMPScript = new ExternalObject('lib:AdobeXMPScript');       
            results.message = "XMPScript Library loaded";
        }
        catch (e)
        {
            alert("Could not load AdobeXMPScript \r" + e.message);
            results.message = "ERROR Loading AdobeXMPScript: " + e;
            results.line = e.line;
            results.error = true;
        }
    }

    return results;
}
function unloadXMPScript()
{
    var results = new XMPLibMsg("XMPScript Library not loaded", 0, false);

    if( ExternalObject.AdobeXMPScript ) 
    {
        try
        {
            ExternalObject.AdobeXMPScript.unload();
            ExternalObject.AdobeXMPScript = undefined;
            results.message = "XMPScript Library successfully unloaded";
        }
        catch (e)
        {
            results.message = "ERROR unloading AdobeXMPScript: " + e;
            results.line = e.line;
            results.error = true;
        }
    }

    return results;
}
function XMPLibMsg (inMessage, inLine, inError)
{
    this.message = inMessage;
    this.line = inLine;
    this.error = inError;
}
```